# How to match the first word after "by"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textbox where  the user can specified the filters of one search:

- by author
- by title
- by year

How I can match only the word after "by" with regex in JavaScript?

I tried with `by\b(\w*)` and `by\b(.*)\b` but this match the rest of the sentence.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: give some example input and output please

Comment: Can the character between the two words be anything other than a space?

Comment: Why on earth would you do this with a text input and not either a pulldown or radio buttons?

Comment: @Utku Yıldırım: It's already there. In fact it makes up half the question body.

Comment: Others have already told you what *will* work; I thought I'd throw in an explanation of why `by\b(\w*)` *doesn't* work. `\b` doesn't match an actual character; it matches a (zero-width) boundary between a non-word character and a word character. For example, `a\b%` is equivalent to just `a%`. So something like `\w\b\w` can never match anything: it matches two word characters, with the property that one of them is a word character and one is not.

Comment: @Pointy I'm trying to imitate a natural conversation with the user.

Comment: Well, I can't know your application of course, but as you know (or as you'll certainly learn) it's hard to predict exactly how people will respond with natural language. If you have to keep correcting the user until they happen to respond with a particular pattern you expect, then that's probably not an ideal experience.

Comment: @BoltClock No, always is a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var s = 'test by toBeMatched and another work';
var matches = s.match(/by\s(\w*)/, ''); // ["by toBeMatched ", "toBeMatched"]
console.log(matches[1]); // "toBeMatched"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will match by, followed by one or more spaces (i.e.: new word), followed by everything until the next space (or end of line) (i.e.: the word you're looking for):
`by\s+([^\s]+)`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/by (\w+)/
```

Assuming by is followed by a space.

Comment: The lazy match will cause this to only match the first letter of the next word.